# Retrieving the data from the database based on the parameter

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api

`ValuesController.cs` (sending the HTTP request such as GET, POST, DELETE and etc):

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    Database_Access_Data.db dblayer = new Database_Access_Data.db();

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Values/SendLocation")]
    public IHttpActionResult SendLocation([FromBody]Location cs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            dblayer.SendLocation(cs);

            return Ok("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok("Something went Wrong" + e);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Values/GetLocationHistory")]
    public DataSet GetLocationHistory()
    {
        DataSet ds = dblayer.GetLocationHistory();
        return ds;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Values/SendDistance")]
    public IHttpActionResult SendDistance([FromBody]Location cs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            dblayer.SendDistance(cs);

            return Ok("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok("Something went Wrong" + e);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Values/GetUser")]
    public DataSet GetUser()
    {
        DataSet ds = dblayer.GetUser();
        return ds;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Values/FlagingDevice")]
    public IHttpActionResult FlagingDevice([FromBody]Timer cs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            dblayer.FlagingDevice(cs);

            return Ok("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok("Something went Wrong" + e);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Values/SendBox")]
    public IHttpActionResult SendBox([FromBody]Box cs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            dblayer.SendBox(cs);

            return Ok("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok("Something went Wrong" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

`db.cs` (used to call the stored procedure as well as sending the parameter):

```
public class db
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localhost"].ConnectionString);

    Location cs = new Location();

    public void SendLocation(Location cs)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SendGPS",con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceImei", cs.DeviceImei);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude",cs.Latitude);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude",cs.Longitude);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Distance", cs.Distance);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationSend",cs.LocationSend);

        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    public DataSet GetLocationHistory()
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GetLocationHistory", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
    }

    public DataSet GetUser()
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GetUser", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
    }

    public void SendDistance(Location cs)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SendDistance", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceImei", cs.DeviceImei);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Distance", cs.Distance);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationSend", cs.LocationSend);

        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    public void FlagingDevice(Timer cs)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("FlagingDevice", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interval", cs.Interval);

        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    public void SendBox(Box cs)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SendBox", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", cs.Id);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PollingStationID", cs.PollingStationID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceImei", cs.DeviceImei);

        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

The stored procedure that used to return the data from the table:

```
     SET ANSI_NULLS ON
     GO
     SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
     GO

     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FlagingDevice]
         @Interval INT 
     AS 
         DECLARE @Time DATETIME

         IF @Interval = 5
         BEGIN 
             SET @Time = (SELECT MAX(LocationSend) FROM dbo.Location)

             SELECT D.imei, L.*, L1.*
             FROM Device D
             OUTER APPLY
                 (SELECT  * 
                  FROM dbo.Location L1
                  WHERE L1.DeviceImei = D.Imei 
                  GROUP BY DeviceImei, Latitude, Longitude, Distance, LocationSend
                  HAVING DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LocationSend, @Time) <= @Interval) AS L
             OUTER APPLY
                 (SELECT TOP 1 L4.ID AS 'Station', L3.Name
                  FROM [dbo].[ElectionDivision] L3, dbo.PollingStation L4
                  WHERE L.Latitude IS NOT NULL 
                    AND L.Longitude IS NOT NULL 
                    AND L.Distance IS NOT NULL 
                    AND L.DeviceImei = D.ImeI) AS L1
          END
          ELSE IF @Interval = 0
          BEGIN 
              SELECT D.imei, L.*, L1.*
              FROM Device D
              OUTER APPLY
                  (SELECT TOP 1 * 
                   FROM dbo.Location L1
                   WHERE L1.DeviceImei = D.Imei 
                   ORDER BY (LocationSend) DESC) AS L
              OUTER APPLY
                  (SELECT TOP 1 L4.ID AS 'Station', L3.Name
                   FROM [dbo].[ElectionDivision] L3, dbo.PollingStation L4
                   WHERE L.Latitude IS NOT NULL 
                     AND L.Longitude IS NOT NULL 
                     AND L.Distance IS NOT NULL 
                     AND L.DeviceImei = D.ImeI) AS L1
      END
```

**Update**: I am using sqldatareader and put the data into a list but not sure how to return the FlaggingDevice Method as shown in the valuescontroller class. Should i be creating the list inside a class or something else. Any Suggestions ?

```
        public List<FlagingDevice> FlagingDevice(FlagingDevice cs)
        {

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("FlagingDevice", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interval", cs.Interval);
            con.Open();
            com.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader())
            {

                int movieGenreIDIndex = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("DeviceImei");
                int movieIDIndex = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Latitude");
                int genreIDIndex = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Longitude");
                int genreIDIndex1 = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Distance");
                int genreIDIndex2 = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("LocationSend");
                int genreIDIndex3 = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Station");
                int genreIDIndex4 = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Name");
                while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    student.Add(new FlagingDevice()
                    {
                        DeviceImei = sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(movieGenreIDIndex) ? null : sqlDataReader.GetString(movieGenreIDIndex),
                        Latitude = sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(movieIDIndex) ? null : sqlDataReader.GetString(movieIDIndex),
                        Longitude = sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(genreIDIndex) ? null : sqlDataReader.GetString(genreIDIndex),
                        Distance = sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(genreIDIndex1) ? null : sqlDataReader.GetString(genreIDIndex1),
                        LocationSend = sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(genreIDIndex2) ? null : Convert.ToString(sqlDataReader["LocationSend"]),
                        Name = sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(genreIDIndex4) ? null : sqlDataReader.GetString(genreIDIndex4)



                    });






                }
                sqlDataReader.Close();
                con.Close();
                return student;


            }




        }
```

Comment: Problem is i only managed to send the interval to the stored procedure but not able to retrieve the data based on the interval. Even i have created a separate method for the get request, the stored procedure would require me for the interval.

Comment: Images of code are a pain to work with.  You will attract better quality answers if you post the code as well formatted text.  Case in point; I can't be bothered, beyond making this comment, because the code is too hard to read.

Comment: which controller action is not returning data? The stored proc `FlagingDevice` is returning data, but you dataaccess method is not reading data from DataReader after executing com.ExecuteNonQuery(). Also your method return type for `FlagingDevice1 is void then how will you send the data back to controller?

Comment: The FlagingDevice Controller action is only returning Success. For the FlagingDevice1(Ignore), i created that to test if the method did return some value

Comment: First, add "set nocount on" as the first statement in every stored procedure. Next, stop using [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Next - stop the lazy coding and specify which columns you NEED in your resultsets. Do not use the asterisk. Only select the needed columns, not all of them. You have duplicate columns in your resultsets that you don't need. Lastly, your proc does nothing if parm is not zero or five. Is this wise?

Comment: And one more comment. Order of rows usually matters. You do not order your resultsets - do not assume that there is an order just because you observe one when development or testing - especially on lightly loaded machines.

Comment: When asking why something doesn't work, you should provide a [mcve], and a clear problem statement and the actual and expected outcome.

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection SqlCommand SqlDataAdapter.and SqlDataReader are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection, as that will be done by the Dispose when it exits that block.